# Как создать такой список

Tags: android, android-studio, recyclerview, customview, изображения

Привет. Как в андроид создать такой список? 
Как создать разное количество елементов в строке и как кастомизировать их ширину?[image: пример нужного списка]

Answer (score 2):

Лучше всего для такого вида списка подходит [`FlexboxLayoutManager`](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout/#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview) для компоновки айтемов по мере заполнения экрана. Данный менеджер входит в библиотеку Google Flexbox-layout

Comment: FlexBox нормально работает с ресурсами приложения, но когда нужно загрузить изображение с интернета, то начинаются жуткие лаги. как это можно нормально исправить?

Answer (score 2):

Это можно сделать с `ConstraintLayout` с чейном `layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`

[Подробнее здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/company/touchinstinct/blog/326814/)

Comment: как его использовать в адаптере? у мене есть много картинок так что не получится вручну прописать

Comment: Задаешь лейаут строки в адаптере