# Отображение фото в виде мозаики или в виде коллажа в андроид

Tags: android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Пишу отображение постов из Вконтакте. Подскажите пожалуйста библиотеку или алгоритм для того чтобы отобразить все фото в виде мозаики или коллажа. Имеется `CardView`, в котором нужно реализовать данную задумку. Спасибо!

Comment: Используйте RecyclerView c кастомным или стандартным LayoutManager

Comment: А по подробнее?

Comment: Существует огромное количество туториалов в интернете, тут дело не одной страницы) Но вкратце RecyclerView это View элемент который позволяет "переиспользовать" вьюшки, то есть делать таблицы или мозаики. Вы передаете ему массив данных (фото), определяете адаптер, который будет связывать данные с ячейками (как правило однотипными) и LayoutManager, (стандартные GridLayoutManager и ListLayoutManager) для сетки или списка соответственно. LayoutManager описывает поведение вашей таблицы и расположение элементов.

Comment: [StaggeredGridLayoutManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) или [Flexbox Layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы, но вы не совсем понимаете то, что требуется. StaggeredGridLayoutManager и Flexbox Layout (хотя это не точно) вообще не подойдут, т. к. фото внутри карточки, которая и является элементом RecyclerView.

Comment: В идеале нужно так: MyView v = new MyView(); v.addImg(model.getDrowble());

Comment: Добавьте что ли картинку чего вы хотите, чтобы мы совсем понимали что требуется.

Comment: Добавил. Вот примерно так. Но если ещё и адаптироваться по высоте будет, то вообще идеально.

Comment: [FlexboxLayoutManager](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout#flexboxlayoutmanager-within-recyclerview) для RecyclerView. Возможный [дубликат вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690539/177345)

Comment: Ну и где на картинке карточки, которые являются элементом RecyclerView? Ощущение, что вы сами не совсем понимаете, что требуется.

Comment: На фото просто пример того, как должны отображаться фотки внутри одной CardView. А таких CardView в RecyclerView может быть много. Что непонятного? Вы разве не видели как выглядят посты с множеством картинок в соц сетях?

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Ранее я искал как создать такой же список, но не смог найти простого способа.
Если использовать Flexbox, то при загрузке картинки начинаются подлагивания, перестройка плиток. Не совсем то что нужно.
Ссылка на мой вопрос: [Как создать такой список](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/690539/232291)

Если ваш список должен крутится по горизонтали то используйте staggeredgridlayoutmanager.